# How to get more precision in calculation

Tags: r, precision

Currently R is rounding the calculation but if I want to get at least 120 digits post the decimal, how do I go about doing that in R?

```
 0.8/0.022332323

[1] 35.82252
```

Is there any default or setting so that it considers at least 120 digits post decimal?
If not 120 can I make it at least 20 digits?

Comment: You would need to use a package which implements higher-precision decimal types. Floats just don't have that much precision. Even 20 digits isn't possible with 64-bit floats.

Comment: mfpr supports 128 bit floats https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2020/03/18/gnu-mpfrr-wrapper/

Answer (score 4):

Try package `Rmpfr`.

```
library(Rmpfr)

b <- ceiling(log2(10)*120)
x <- mpfr(0.8, precBits = b)
d <- mpfr(0.022332323, precBits = b)

x/0.022332323
1 'mpfr' number of precision  399   bits 
#[1] #35.822516090242828897953439868674559527396865046088517580669608395416394154166154302983768871199759705245811245184299832707

identical(x/0.022332323, x/d)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

R isn't rounding quite as much as you think it is. With base R, you can **print** 20 digits after the decimal place in this example (more precisely, you can print up to 22 significant digits; in this case 20 of them are after the decimal place). However, as commented by John Coleman, you won't get that much accuracy with R's double-precision floats (64 bits, of which 53 are mantissa, so we get `53/log2(10)` = approx. 16 decimal places of precision).

Comparing base-R result to the `Rmpfr` results shown by @RuiBarradas, we see that they first diverge at digit 18.

```r
print( 0.8/0.022332323, digits = 22)
## base-R 35.82251609024282856808
## Rmpfr  35.8225160902428288979534 ...
# digits  12 345678901234567890
```