# Big numbers value is changing itself

Tags: r, gmp

Suppose I have big numbers such as this: `10.295.419.305.791.578.917.358.173.519.057.891.283.897.623.986`

```
library(gmp)
as.bigz(10295419305791578917358173519057891283897623986)
```

And this might outputs:

```
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 10295419305791579051260295299235939155628261376
```

Visually the value `10.295.419.305.791.579.051.260.295.299.235.939.155.628.261.376` is already different compared the input (begins after 15 digits from beginning)

My question: are there any explanation to this? is it because of numeric error before it being converted to big integer?

While I still find a way to get the accurate value by adding quotes.. such as:

```
as.bigz("10295419305791578917358173519057891283897623986")
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 10295419305791578917358173519057891283897623986
```

Comment: Yes, R typically reads numbers as double precision floating point numbers, so when you run `as.bigz(######)` it's like you're running `as.bigz(convert_to_floating_point(######))` -- so you will already lose precision. In contrast, a character string in R can be as long as you want and will not be altered en route to your function.

Comment: `options(scipen = 50); 10295419305791578917358173519057891283897623986` Note how just inputing a very large number will often output a different number starting in the ~15th decimal place due to the floating point conversion.

Comment: I see.. So every number either its numeric and integer small or big that we input in console, will always take a floating point conversion process first? @JonSpring

Comment: Right -- base R doesn't have a conception of "numbers" that are more precise than 53 bits; it will work with numbers using their IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point representation: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f  As you noted, if you want to feed a more precise number into a function, it has to be as a character string, which can be effectively unlimited in precision.

Comment: Put the input number between quotes: `gmp::as.bigz("10295419305791578917358173519057891283897623986")`.

Comment: This type of question has come up in various forms many times. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51490022/4408538 https://stackoverflow.com/q/68050209/4408538 https://stackoverflow.com/q/67951564/4408538 https://stackoverflow.com/q/65434297/4408538 to name a few